# flutter error while conect to xcode simulator

Tags: flutter, xcode, compiler-errors

I installed Flutter and followed the steps to the letter. When I use the "Flutter doctor" command, it tells me that everything is fine. However, when I do a "flutter run", it does not let me access my iOS simulator, even though I am seeing that it does work separately. How can I start using Flutter correctly?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKT6A.png)

I've already tried to restart Flutter, followed all the documentation instructions, even followed tutorials on YouTube. However, it still doesn't let me do it. I also updated everything to make sure an old version is not the issue, but it seems I haven't solved it yet.

I just hope to be able to work with Flutter and have it work well, as well as being able to see what I do in the Xcode simulator.